Expo app.config.ts: Add signingConfig.release section to build.gradle file
I'm pretty new to Expo and I like the new prebuild to generate ios and android native projects from a config, but I can't find how to add my signingConfig for release to build.gradle.
I can't be the first to need this but I have a really hard time finding a plugin (so strange that it's not in the ExpoConfig, is it so uncommon for expo apps to reach production?)

I needed the same thing for my local build but couldn't find what I was looking for. I created an npm package called expo-signed, and I hope it will be useful to you.
https://github.com/akayakagunduz/expo-signed
npx expo install expo-signed

